# Calculate natural frequency and damping co-efficient

Tags: matlab, embedded, signal-processing, simulink, resolver

In one of my assignment, I am trying to implement all digital phase locked loop in simulink. I found a journal which explains this concept. The figure below shows the concept used in PLL.[image: Phase locked loop]
I am trying to implement this in matlab simulink. But how do I find out the values of Wo(natural frequency) and ζ(damping coefficient) of this system(second order system). Without these values I can not proceed with simulink model.

Comment: The standard text for this is "Phaselock Techniques" by Floyd M. Gardner. Its been around for decades with the 3rd addition published in 2005. You'll find all you you ever wanted to know about the above system in there.